# JRuby on Rails post data cut short

Tags: post, jruby, truncation

I creating a  site in JRuby on Rails  (JRuby 1.3.0 ).  I am using Tomcat with it also.

I am posting data to the server with a POST form.  The post goes ok but is truncated when it gets to the controller to around 1000 characters.

I have tried using JRuby 1.4RC1 to see the issue disappears but the problem is still present.

I decided to try Ruby on Rails with webrick and the post data is not truncated.

Has anyone used JRuby on Rails and come across this issue at all?

Its a very strange issue hopefully you guys know what I am talking about :-/

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make sure you're using the [latest version](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/jruby/rack/jruby-rack/0.9.5/jruby-rack-0.9.5.jar) of JRuby-Rack (0.9.5)? We did have a few issues with POST truncation in earlier versions. See [JRUBY_RACK-15](http://kenai.com/jira/browse/JRUBY_RACK-15), [JRUBY_RACK-10](http://kenai.com/jira/browse/JRUBY_RACK-10), [JRUBY_RACK-4](http://kenai.com/jira/browse/JRUBY_RACK-4).

Comment: Hey, I have run this command "jruby -S gem list" and it lists the rack version as this "rack (1.0.0)", is this the latest version? Cheers

Comment: I believe so. Double-check by running "jruby -S gem install rack" again.

Comment: Yea, 1.0.0 is definitely installed.  Very strange that the data is being cut short :-S  Do you know how this can be fix or will it be a bugfix in future release of JRuby?  Cheers

Comment: Issue discovered :) Was basically an out of date jruby-rack-0.9.5.jar file, i was still using a nightly build jar, jruby-rack-0.9.5-20090625.190033-5.jar, updated that to the latest and all is well.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if the values are actually being sent to the server?

Also, are you running webrick or mongrel?  Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: I have tried looking at firebug and checking what is sent, all of the data is being sent.  I am running jruby 1.3.1 on rails 2.3.3 with warbler and jboss, I am not behind a proxy server.